# Macvim: Modify the content of the clipboard register before pasting it

Tags: vim, clipboard, macvim

Let us assume that I select some text in Safari and copy it to the clipboard, for example "foo, bar" (without the quotation marks). I can see now that it is available in Macvim in the `"*` register by typing `:reg`. I can copy the content of this register into the Vim editor with a shortcut or using edit->paste. But how do I modify the content of this register (or any register for that matter), before pasting it. As an example, how would I apply a search and replace routine, such as searching for the "," and replacing it with a ".", such that the register now contains "foo. bar"?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:reg *
original content

let @*='altered content'

:reg * 
altered content
```

You can do that with every named register.

Your example can be dealt with:

```
let @a=substitute(@*,',','.','g')
"ap
```

But you should probably make some backup before actually doing anything too complicated:

```
:reg a
original content

let a_orig = @a

let @a='altered content'
"ap
altered content

let @a=a_orig

:reg a
original content
```

Comment: @romainl Thanks, but when I wanted to replace the linebreak ```^J``` with ```" "``` it failed. I thought maybe the linebreak is not ```^``` appending ```J``` so I just copied it from the register when running ```:reg```, but also got a wrong result. Can I replace the linebreak with a space?

Comment: @leoadams, In Vim `^J` is actually a single character. You can insert it by typing `<C-v><C-j>`.